# Replacing SUMIF that contains a word in excel to python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to replace a process I'm doing in EXCEL with a python data frame & pandas library
The process is to sum cost and conversions for all keywords that contains that row keyword in the same device

for example for black keyword on mobile I want to sum the cost and conversion of all keywords that contain black on mobile, for cost the final result will be 19 as we have black (1.5) + black tie (3) + black ties (5.2) + black shirt (2.3) + black ties and shirts (3) + res and black tie (0.5)

[image: table example]

Comment: What have you tried ? What is the problem ?

Comment: I tried looping through each row and use .str.contains, but I don't know how to check for each row against all data frame rows, and to sum specific column

Answer (score 1):

You can create a df from your html with read_html and then sum it

```
df = pd.read_html(your_html)[0]
df[(df['Keyword'].str.contains('black', na = False) & (df['device']=='Mobile' ))]['cost'].sum()
Out[116]: 19.0
```

if you want your filtered html then

```
df[(df['Keyword'].str.contains('black', na = False) & (df['device']=='Mobile' ))].to_html()
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>Keyword</th>\n      <th>device</th>\n      <th>cost</th>\n      <th>conversions</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>black</td>\n      <td>Mobile</td>\n      <td>1.5</td>\n      <td>0</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>1</th>\n      <td>black tie</td>\n      <td>Mobile</td>\n      <td>3.0</td>\n      <td>1</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2</th>\n      <td>black ties</td>\n      <td>Mobile</td>\n      <td>5.2</td>\n      <td>2</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>3</th>\n      <td>black shirt</td>\n      <td>Mobile</td>\n      <td>2.3</td>\n      <td>0</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>4</th>\n      <td>black ties and shirts</td>\n      <td>Mobile</td>\n      <td>3.0</td>\n      <td>2</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>5</th>\n      <td>red and black tie</td>\n      <td>Mobile</td>\n      <td>0.5</td>\n      <td>1</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>7</th>\n      <td>shirt black</td>\n      <td>Mobile</td>\n      <td>3.5</td>\n      <td>2</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>
```

To run in a loop

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if 'black' in row['Keyword'] and row['device'] == 'Mobile':
        print(row)
```

Comment: But how do I run it on every row? instead of str.contains('black', na = False), str.contains(df['Keyword'][row], na = False)

Comment: you dont need run a loop for every row but still  updated to show how you can print required rows from there on you can do what ever you want